# Is this a scam or is it legit?

Tags: wallet, fraud, watch-only

So this guy sent me a watch-only wallet address. I open it up and there's some decent crypto in there. However, he said I have to go to a bitcoin atm and "pay the fees to access the coins"
With it being a watch only wallet is it even possible to "activate it" to become a wallet I can access and withdraw from.

1. Is this even a thing.
2. Can I report this as a scam.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common advance fee scam

Comment: The address isn't yours. So this guy is asking you to buy bitcoins and send them to someone else's address and he's telling you whatever he thinks you need to hear to get you to do that.